# Setting idle timeout for websocket connections using androidasync

Tags: android, sockets, websocket, timeout, androidasync-koush

Can I set an idle timeout for an inactive websocket connection using the available APIs of AndroidAsync or should I code my own timer?

I need to cleanly kill the websocket connection if it's idle for 3 minutes.

Comment: have you got an answer? I am also looking for an answer. Thnks